# Can I add elements to a java queue using array without defining the front and the rear? I am having trouble with this

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I am having trouble using enqueue and dequeue functions. I want to add elements without defining the front and rear in my scope. 
    public class MyStaticQueue 
    {
    private int items[] ;
    private int noOfItems = 0;
    private int maxItems;

```
public MyStaticQueue(int m)
{
    this.maxItems = m;
    this.items = new int[maxItems];
    this.noOfItems = 0;

}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(noOfItems == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public int first()
{

    return items[0];
}

public void add(int item)
{
    for (int i=0; i<items[maxItems]; i++) 
    {

        if (items[i] == 0) 
        {
            items[i] = item;
        }
        noOfItems++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you show us some of your code. I have a hard time figuring what you are actually talking about.

Comment: Does this help?